# How to create multiple DBAccss databases in ios App?

Tags: objective-c, orm, dbaccess

How can I use multiple dbaccess database in one app?
For example: If I have two database namely "database1" and "database2". Now, How can I store data in specific database and retrieve from it?

Answer (score 0):

DBObjects have a method on them called, storageDatabaseForClass.  If you respond to this method then another database will be created of that name, and that class will be created and persisted within it.

```
+ (NSString *)storageDatabaseForClass {
    return @"database2";
}
```

There is a caveat, that being that queries are not optimised across the different storage bases, you will also not be able to perform JOIN operations across them, and if you are using subqueries would will not be able to perform them inline but will have to perform them outside and pass the results into the query as a parameter.

Thanks
Adrian

Comment: After creating another database, how can I store and retrieve data in any specific database?Foe ex.- I want to store some data in database 1 and some in database 2.

Comment: Okay, well an object has a specific storage database, so you would not, for instance be able to store some of classA in database1 and some in database2.  classA will always be stored 100% within it's allocated database.

Comment: We will add it to the future features list, but I don't think it will be a general requirement.  And the list is already pretty long as it stands.